# Group unique ids per value in column - Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe where I need to find out how many unique id's that exists per url (which is another column in the dataframe).

The dataframe looks like this:

```
12333   google.com
13232   yahoo.com
12333   yahoo.com
12333   google.com
```

In this table the result would be:

```
google.com 1
yahoo.com 2
```

I've amongst other things tried this:

```
pdf.groupby(['url', 'id']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0: 'count'})
```

which gives me this df:

```
google.com 12333 2
yahoo.com 13232 1
yahoo.com 13333 1
```

I'm just not sure how to get to the last step.

Comment: Need `df.groupby(['url'])['id'].nunique().reset_index()`, it is dupe :(

Comment: Ohk whats the last step ?